# casein admin user got error when running project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using casein gem in my project

all around my app I give casein error in casein/admin_user.rb model that says:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'validate_email_field=' for #<Class:xxxxxx>
Did you mean?  validates_numericality_of`

whats the problem?

casein version: 5.3.0

ruby version: jruby 9.2.5.0

rails version: 5.2.1

Comment: what type of class is `#<Class:xxxxxx>`? It means the `validate_email_field` doesn't exist in that class. Either you have mis-specified the name, or you haven't added the method yet, to that class.

Comment: I only added casein in empty project.
it should be casein internal error or version bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Casein version 5.4.0 because 5.3.0 version is not compatible with this rails version.